# How to pass parameter in wordpress url

Tags: wordpress

```
function signal_adder_form(){
        form_css();
    form_dpicker();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $da=$_POST['to'];
    $our_date = str_replace( "/", "-", $da);    
}
   echo '<div class="signali">';
   echo '<h1>Add Signal</h1>';
   echo '<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">';
   echo ' <div class="text">Select Currency</div>';
   echo '<div class="itemi">      ';
   echo ' <div class="labeli"><label for="cur1">From</label></div>';
   echo '<div class="inputis" class="small"><select name="cur1" id="cur1">';
   list_of_currency();
   echo '</select></div>';
   echo '<div class="labeli"><label for="cur2">To Which</label></div>';
   echo '<div class="inputis"><select name="cur2" id="cur2">';
   list_of_currency();
   echo '</select></div>';
   echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<div class="text">Date</div>';

}
```

`http://localhost/theme/wp-admin/edit.php?page=addsignal`

this is my url in wordpress admin i want to pass a parameter in it like

`http://localhost/theme/wp-admin/edit.php?page=addsignal&add=true`

i am new in this work so i don't know how do i implement it

---

also tell me  when i have edit page how will i implement edit link i do in php

like " ?id=23"

how do i do in wordpress admin panel

Comment: Admin edit url: yoursite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post=23&action=edit

Comment: As for the first question, I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: like i didn't pass any form action automatically wordpress do it php_self ... but what if i want to pass a parameter on form submit...

Comment: I would use POST and not GET for a form submit

Comment: i add form on tab... but i made this form to add entries i make a function which list all db entries to edit and delete but when i click edit in php we pass edit.php?id=1 how do i do this in wordpress
`http://localhost/theme/wp-admin/edit.php?page=addsignal` what if i want to pass a parameter and how to implement url on edit button

Comment: How are you calling the function `signal_adder_form()`?